# Why Connecting using include once is failing with pdo?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Why Connecting using include once is failing with pdo?
When I connect to the database including a connection page it gave me an error, but when I put the connecting code in and I remove include I do not get errors. What might be the problem?

```
Error Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\tish\A\view.php on line 167
```

Connecting page:

```
<?php
  function connected_Db(){
    try {
      $con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tish_database;charset=utf8','root','');
    } catch(PDOException $e){
      echo 'Connection failed'.$e->getMessage();
    }
  }
  connected_Db();
?>
```

the way I include it in other pages:

```
include_once('pdo.inc.php');
connected_Db();
global $con;
```

Comment: Where's the rest of the code? You're missing at least `$con->prepare()` somewhere

Comment: can you make sure the file is being included properly? Are both files in same directory ?

Comment: @Minesh Yes they are both in the same Directory

Comment: @sjdaws  not beause if I connect directly it works and I did not post the other page not to get people bored of the long codes please check it on http://pastebin.com/fttmjuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make a *function* variable global from the global scope. The variable `$con` has long been GC'ed: it's deallocated once the function has returned. Try this:

```
function connected_Db()
{
   return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tish_database;charset=utf8','root','');
}
//global scope:
$con = connect_Db();
```

If you insist on using the `global` keyword, which is *not* a great idea, you should've used it like this:

```
function connected_Db()
{
    global $con;//use the global var, set at top of function
    $con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tish_database;charset=utf8','root','');
}
$con = null;// declare global var (optional, but a notice will be issued if not declared)
connect_Db();
var_dump($con);
```

As you can see, I have -like deceze and YourCommonSense suggested- removed the try-catch block (which you don't need here). It also goes to show that you don't really need the function call either. Your script would work perfectly fine (or marginally faster even) if you were to write this:

```
//global scope (or whatever scope you need it to be)
$con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tish_database;charset=utf8','root','');
```

That way, you're not calling a function that needn't be called.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: addressed the issue, and added suggestion of _not_ using a function call at all. Try-Catch-Echo construct was a copy paste of OP anyway...

Comment: Good great help appreciated I am still comparing the answers but yours is one of the most relevant

Answer (score 2):

You never make `$con` available outside of the function `connected_Db`. Learn about [variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). You should `return` it from the function and use it like so:

```
require_once 'pdo.inc.php';

$con = connected_Db();
```

Which also means you should not `catch` connection errors (at least not there), since if the function can't return a PDO connection your script doesn't need to continue.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to tell PDO to throw exceptions on connect errors.
Next, you shouldn't catch them, at least not using try .. catch.

So, the code have to be

pdo.inc.php:

```
<?php
function connected_Db(){
    $dsn  = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tish_database;charset=utf8';
    $opt  = array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
    );
    return new PDO($dsn,'root','', $opt);
}
```

(you may also wish to pass connect options via function parameters)

other file

```
include_once('pdo.inc.php');
$con = connected_Db();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but _"merely copy-pasted from the manual page"_? I don't copy-paste lest I mention the source. I copied the OP's code, and changed the assignment to a return statement. After your just comment I also removed the try-catch block. I can't help finding your accusations slightly offensive

Comment: @Your Common Sense You always come the best if it comes to answers and I am using now yours bacause I feel save with your answer and it worked 100%

Comment: @Elias The Colonel often is offensive, but he's usually also right. ;)

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem  please forgive him on my behalf because its my question all maybe caused this But all I would say guys I thank you all for comming out and help me all answers are relevant here thats why I credited them all although I had to chose 1

Comment: @deceze: fair enough... he is indeed. I forgot this is the internet, a place where generalizations roam freely and reign supreme... in general, that is. I just get rather touchy when I feel I'm being accused of _intellectual theft_. Mustn't cry about it ;-) to humphrey: Don't worry about it

Answer (score 1):

You're using `global` incorrectly. It should go in the function, to specify that the variable is from outside the function, i.e. in the global scope.

e.g.

```
function connected_Db()
{
    global $con;

    $con = null;
    try
    {
       $con = new PDO(...);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        die('Could not connect: '.$e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

But it's better to return the connection rather than pull it in from global scope.

i.e.

```
function connected_Db()
{
    try
    {
       return new PDO(...);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        die('Could not connect: '.$e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a trivial example of how to use `global`. Whether exiting the script is the right thing to do is up to the developer. If all the function is going to do is call "new PDO()" and return the result, there's no need for the function, and an `echo` just as much probably doesn't belong there, if you want to get picky.

Comment: Your answer worked first for me thanks let me test also other peoples answer then I will decide "appreciated"